# Change response URL on Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, apartment-gem

I am trying to change my response URL to redirect (without redirect) to custom subdomain. I am using `devise` and `apartment` and I am trying to use User's subdomain after successful request.

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action  :switch_tenant_response


  def switch_tenant_response
    response.headers["SERVER_NAME"] = 'tenant_name.lvh.me' # does not work
  end
```

I would like to request being sent to `lvh.me` (domain name for localhost) be redirected to `tenant_name.lvh.me`. Also I would like to avoid doing this in middleware (but if there is a way to do it please let me know) since on rails app I have access to devise's `current_user`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question, but is this what you're looking for? `redirect_to some_path(subdomain: false) #redirect to localhost or whatever the host is without subdomain` and `redirect_to some_path(subdomain: tenant_subdomain_from_a_variable) #redirects to provided subdomain`